# Can't create subscriptions on Stripe

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I can't create stripe subscription due to `Missing required param: items.`. I request it with `items` although.

The error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-missing",
    "message": "Missing required param: items.",
    "param": "items",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

The code:

```
    const stripeCustomer = await stripe.customers.create({
      name: name,
      email: email,
      plan: basicPlan,
    })
    const stripeSubscription = await stripe.subscriptions.create({
      items: [{ plan: basicPlan }],
      customer: stripeCustomer.id,
    })
```

Stripe Customer account was successfully added.

Comment: are you sure basicPlan contains the id of the plan? I also don't see plan as parameter for Create customer, maybe I'm looking at a different API version. But I would make sure basicPlan has the actual Id for the plan... try a test by hard coding it perhaps.https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/create?lang=node https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=node

Comment: Yeah. basicPlan is is like 'plan_xxxxxxxx'

Comment: Sorry my bacic plan was undefined.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Got the same problem. I've found out I'm lacking some package details

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30006963)